# Want to develope multiple apk to upload on google play for single application of indic font

Tags: android

I am developing indic font application for android but some devices not able to render indic fonts for that I am going to use images of indic text ,that will created on server side and my application going to fetch it at runtime this thing is doable for me.

I want to make two apk for upload on google play.

1)I can upload multiple apk for single application

using this [Link shows how to upload multiple apk](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SingleAPK)

Is it a best solution to create multiple apk for this.

reasons to make multiple apk are for these are 
1) Device which can render indic font use text rendering apk for fast downloading because images of text slow down my app.

help me what is the best solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't be able to use multiple .APKs for this, and you probably don't want to.

[The Official Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SupportedFilters) state that you wouldn't be able to filter by font availability.

However, what you should do, is use a single APK, and detect at runtime if Indic fonts work on a given device, and switch between those features at runtime.